# Hangfire : How to stop processing of background jobs and process them in a certain time period

Tags: c#, hangfire

We have a scenario where we want the jobs to keep on queuing in the server but not processing. Processing of jobs should be done in a specific time period for e.g., 11 am to 13 pm. For recurring jobs, this can be done by using CRON expressions. Is there any way we can achieve the same thing with Background jobs enqueued.

For normal processing, we are queuing in user-defined queues as :

```
var state = new EnqueuedState(queue.Name);
_client.Create(methodCall, state);
```

_client is of type `IBackgroundJobClient`.

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule a background job from another background job. So, you could maybe put the scheduling decision logic inside the method you are scheduling.

Say you have the following method:

```cs
void DoSomethingAndScheduleAgain()
{
   // Do some work...

   bool shouldContinue = //Some condition (e.g. it is not 13 pm yet)
   if (shouldeContinue)
      BackgroundJob.Schedule(DoSomethingAndScheduleAgain), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
   else
      BackgroundJob.Schedule(DoSomethingAndScheduleAgain), TimeSpan.FromHours(22)); //Wait until tomorrow
}
```

Now you just schedule this method for the first time and the method will continue scheduling itself when needed.

```cs
BackgroundJob.Schedule(DoSomethingAndScheduleAgain), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

Comment: BackgroundJob.Schedule will add to the default queue, which we don't want. Sorry to miss this point in the question earlier.